# Methods of finding SQL Servers in a network programatically

Tags: sql-server, visual-c++

I'm trying to detect Microsoft SQL Servers in a network. First of all, one would read Microsoft docs on how to do it, right? So I read about ODBC's `SQLBrowseConnect` and went with it. I found all SQL Server Express Editions I had installed and was happy, until I gave finished product to client for testing. They say it didn't find any servers.

Turns out that depending on operating system, ODBC SQL Server client used and **other, unknown to me factors**, I can detect some or none of running servers. When compared to output of `sqlcmd -L` my detection with SQLBrowseConnect looks bleak. We were moving my app between computers and depending on SQL Server ODBC driver version, SQL Server Native Client version (I've used both) and Windows version, results were different, but some servers were not detected at all, while sqlcmd detects them.

I then tried this method of broadcasting UDP packet of `0x02` to port 1434 where Browser listens, but I got no more than SQLBrowseConnect.

By the way: I tried today Management Studio on two of my computers - same version, different Windows. On Win7 detected 3 servers, on Win2003 detected 6 at the same time.

There's obviously more methods to detect SQL Servers, because on computers where I can't get any results, my colleague gets all servers, but he's using Embarcadero Delphi as a component, which, I believe, uses .NET provider.

I just read there's WMI method too, but I believe you have to supply user and password of target computer, which obviously is useless, as I would need users to supply multiple passwords for multiple servers, which they don't even know. Unless I misunderstand something.

Anyway, please share any method that can be implemented in c or c++, anything. Please note: I can't ask for passwords to computers to connect with WMI.

Comment: Are you scouring for all sql instances on your network or are you only interested in a few endpoints of importance?

Comment: ALL servers in the local network. Assume I don't know machine names running SQL Server, but want to discover them. (Of course I know, but the goal is to run the utility where it's users would not know, kind of how sqlcmd -L works).

Comment: Go brute force! 1433 port scan [half-open](http://nmap.org/nmap_doc.html#syn) your network range. :)

Comment: OK, so assume I do so, all I get is IP address (possibly computer/server name) of the thing that responded. Can I safely assume port 1433 is UNNAMED instance of SQL Server? (e.g. how to tell whether I should connect to COMPUTERNAME or COMPUTERNAME\INSTANCE)? (BTW: SQL Server Native Client sometimes shows both COMPUTERNAME and COMPUTERNAME\INSTANCE, even when you can't connect to the former, because there's nothing else than named instance started).